# Timeout within array executes does not execute first

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to print text with timeout within map function, and then say that it's done, but 'done' is printed before the array and I can't figure out how to fix it:

```js
const arrayImages = [
    [
        {
            url: 'img/man.jpg',
        }, 
        {
            url: 'img/bike.jpg',
        }, 
        {
            url: 'img/sun.jpg'
        },
    ]
]

function clickMe(){  
arrayImages[0].map((element, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     alert(index);
     if (index === 5)
       return;
  },2000 * index);  
 });

  alert("Done");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` *schedules* the task for some time in the future. Then immediately after you schedule them, you call your alert. Perhaps only alert done when `index == arrayImages[0].length`.

Comment: @mykaf, `index` will never get that value.

Comment: Wow, I know that and even had it at the back of my mind when I typed that. `arrayImagse[0].length - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `alert` is executed synchronously -- long before any of the asynchronous callback calls are made. The place to show that "done" is when the last `setTimeout` callback is executed, so when `index` is `arrayImages[0].length-1`.

But this is not a very elegant way to do it. Moreover, `map` returns an array, so that is not really the appropriate looping method to use.

Instead, look at promises.

First promisify `setTimeout` and then loop with a plain `for` loop within an `async` function:

```js
// Promisify setTimeout
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const arrayImages = [[{ url: 'img/man.jpg',},{ url: 'img/bike.jpg',},{ url: 'img/sun.jpg'},]]

async function clickMe() {
    for (const element of arrayImages[0]) {
        await delay(1000);
        console.log(element.url);
    }
    console.log("done");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```